# jQuery's .getScript()... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, getscript

I'm programming an iPhone app with Phonegap. I have local `.html` and `.js` files.  The following is in my `index.html` file:

```
function onBodyLoad() {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);
}

function deviceReady() {
     $.getScript("js/order.js");
}
```

I researched and researched, but just can't figure out why my "order.js" file isn't getting called by the `$.getScript` method.  Any ideas?  Or is there any other way to call this `.js` file within the deviceReady function in my `index.html`?

Comment: Do setup an alert or something similar to log the `deviceready` event firing, I've had a hell-of-a-time with some versions of PhoneGap not firing the `deviceready` event (even though the APIs are available to use).

Comment: Yes, deviceready is firing.  I called other plugins under deviceReady, but just don't know how to call .js files.

Comment: By "local," do you mean `file:///` or `http://localhost/`? Some features are restricted when using `file:`, so setting up an HTTP server may help.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following solution worked very well.

1. Add a custom jQuery function that uses ajax and caches the loaded script:

   ```
   function init()
   {
       // Create a custom cached script importer based on ajax
       jQuery.cachedScript = function(url, options)
       {
           // Allow custom options, but dataType, cache and url are always predefined
           options = $.extend(options || {},
           {
               dataType: "script",
               cache: true,
               url: url
           });
           return jQuery.ajax(options);
       };

       importScripts();
   }
   ```
2. Import the scripts and optionally handle `done` and `fail`:

   ```
   function importScripts()
   {
       $.cachedScript("js/events.js")
           // Wait for the script to be loaded, before adding the listener
           .done(function()
           {
               document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
           });
       $.cachedScript("js/navigation.js");
       $.cachedScript("js/mark.js");
   }
   ```

Thats it : )
More information may be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).